# Why can’t the keys of a Perl hash be retrieved in the order in which they were stored?

Tags: perl

I declared a hash in Perl, and later I added few key-value pairs in a certain order. When I iterate the hash, the key-value pairs are not in the same order in which they were stored. What is the reason?

Comment: Its because data in hash is not stored in any particular order. http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/10/01/hashes.html

Answer (score 11):

Because hash keeps data in order governed by hash function. And good hash functions map keys into hash values which look almost random.

If you want ordered hash in Perl, you can use [`Tie::Hash::Indexed`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::Hash::Indexed) or [`Tie::IxHash`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::IxHash).

Answer (score 5):

Hashmaps in general do not preserve order in any language.

You can sort the keys before iterating them to get sorted order, or if you really need the original insertion ordering then you can preserve that separately in a separate array.

Answer (score 0):

The *reason* hashes don't preserve order is that they are stored in a special structure called a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

When you access `$hash{key}`, under the hood `key` is converted to an index identifying the location of that value.  This allows near-instantaneous access to the hash's contents, even if your hash has a huge number of elements.

In comparison, if a hash were stored in a structure that preserves insertion order (such as a traditional array) it would take a large number of look-ups to find a given element.  If you had an array of a million elements, finding a particular element would take, on average, 500,000 operations.

If the order of insertion is the main way you need to access your data, it is probably better to use a traditional array instead.